# How to swap value pairs restricted by unique index

Tags: hibernate, unique-constraint

We have a Hibernate-based (33.) web application and are finding an issue related to swapping datavalue pairs restricted by a unique index. In our flightticket HBM we have

```
<many-to-one name="participants" class="net.umbrella.entity.ParticipantModel" fetch="select">
    <column name="PARTICIPANTID" not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="flights" class="net.umbrella.entity.FlightModel" fetch="select">
    <column name="FLIGHTID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

It is functionally possible to take a data pair with ticket A assigned to participant P1 plus ticket B assigned to participant P2 and swap the two participants. Ticket A would end up assigned to participant P2, ticket B would be assigned to participant P1. However, FLIGHTID + PARTICIPANTID have a unique constraint.

When Hibernate issues the first update to change participant P1 to P2 on ticket A, a GenericJDBCException is thrown

```
Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object 'FLIGHTTICKET' with unique index 'IDX_FLIGHTTICKET_UQ'
```

Does anyone have a common solution to this?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you have something like this:

```
Participant temp = pair1.getParticipant();
pair1.setParticipant(pair2.getParticipant());
pair2.setParticipant(temp);
```

Instead, just do the following:

```
Participant temp1 = pair1.getParticipant();
Participant temp2 = pair2.getParticipant();
pair2.setParticipant(null);
session.flush();
pair1.setParticipant(temp2);
pair2.setParticipant(temp1);
```

The intermediate flush will make sure only one pair at a time references a participant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, implemented that approach and it works like a charm. Is there any Hibernate configuration that could automate this? Such that the Hibernate batch updater would first update all participants to NULL and then to the new value?

Comment: I don't know of any. BTW, this would probably cause more harm than good: unnecessary updates to the database most of the times, and not null constraint violations. You could also make this constraint deferred if your database supports deferred constraints. This way, the constraint would only be checked at commit time.